# Does every smooth local frame of the tangent bundle correspond to a chart?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, tangent-bundle

Every smooth chart $(U,\phi)$ on a smooth manifold $M$ determines a smooth local frame $U \to TM$ on the tangent bundle, namely $(\partial/\partial x^i)$, where $(x_i)$ are the coordinate functions of $\phi : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$. But is the converse true? Namely, given any smooth local coordinate frame $(\sigma_i) : M \supset V \to TM$, can we construct a chart such that the $\sigma_i$ are partial derivatives of the coordinate functions?

Comment: Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136852/transforming-vectors-to-coordinate-vectors/2573232#2573232). We can find maybe not for all $U$ but possibly a smaller one $V \subseteq U$. The point is to use inverse function theorem around a neighbourhood of a point $p \in U$.

Comment: @Sou Certainly this will create a coordinate chart whose associated frame agrees with the given one at a specified point, but how can we ensure that the frames coincide in a neighborhood of the point as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. If you want the statement is true around a neighborhood you should look at @Neal answer instead of mine in [that post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136852/transforming-vectors-to-coordinate-vectors?noredirect=1&lq=1), which more or less refer to the following theorem.

> The necessary and sufficient condition for a smooth frame $\{X_i\}$ to be expressible as a coordinate frame in some smooth chart is that they are a $\textbf{commuting frame}$, i.e. $[X_i,X_j] = 0$ for all $i$ and $j$. This theorem proved in John Lee's $\textit{Introduction to Smooth Manifolds }$ book at Theorem 18.6 [here](https://books.google.co.id/books?redir_esc=y&hl=id&id=eqfgZtjQceYC&q=commuting+vector+fields#v=snippet&q=commuting%20vector%20fields&f=false).

So not all local frame expressible as coordinate frame. Only the commuting ones.