# Commuting solenoidal fields

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, lie-derivative

Given a pair of smooth divergence free vector fields $X,Y$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there some known characterization whch tells when they do commute?

My approach to solve the problem is to start from the fact that they both preserve the form $\mu=dx^1\wedge ... \wedge dx^n$, then
$[X,Y]=0$ if and only if $$0=i_{[X,Y]}\mu = L_Xi_Y\mu =d(i_X i_Y \mu)+i_X(d(i_Y\mu))=d(i_X i_Y \mu).$$

Hence this $(n-2)-$form should be closed and hence I derive some additional condition on them. Do you suggest a different approach to the problem?

Comment: More general [characterization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635110/does-every-smooth-local-frame-of-the-tangent-bundle-correspond-to-a-chart/3636123#3636123)

Comment: So you suggest that they do commute if and only if they are a part of a coordinate chart, did I undestand correctly? But by the way is there some "differential" condition I can impose on them? @Sou

Comment: Yes you understand correctly. But i don't know about your suggestion.

Comment: Okok no problem, do you know a way to check if they are part of a coordinate chart? @Sou I have studied on Lee's book and I did not find it

Comment: If i'am not given the expression of $X$ and $Y$, i have no clue how to find them. Sorry. You have to talk to someone who really know the subject.

Comment: @Sou Perfect but I think it is enough what you've told me before to solve my problem...just the last question. If I find a pair of fields $Y_1,Y_2$ which commute, then we have $Y_1=\partial_u$, $Y_2=\partial_v$ for two coordinates which do exist thanks to the result you suggested. Then is it true that for any vector field $X$ we have $X=a\partial_u + b\partial_v$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ on the whole manifold where the fields do commute or are $a,b$ just local and hence they are not constant but just smooth functions?

Comment: Based on theorem on the link above, if we have commuting $Y_1,Y_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the existence of $(u,v)$ is local around each point. So given any vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for each point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there is a local coordinates $(u^1,u^2,u^3,\dots,u^n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ around $x$, say on $U_x \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\partial_{u^1} = Y_1$ and $\partial_{u^2} = Y_2$. Hence in $U_x$, the expression for $X$ is $X = a Y_1 + bY_2 + X^3 \partial_{u^3} + \cdots + X^n \partial_{u^n}$, where $a,b,X^3,\dots,X^n$ all are local smooth functions on $U_x$.

Comment: @Sou ok so we are not sure that $[X,Y_i]=[X,\partial_{u_1}]=0$ right? Not even for the case $n=2$, thanks

Comment: Yes correct. Welcome.