# Use of chain rule in Transforming vectors to coordinate vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I don't follow Loring Tu's use of the chain rule in a proof to problem 8.9 (Introduction to Manifolds). I'll only focus on the relevant excerpt.

Let $(V, y^1, \ldots, y^n)$ by a chart about $p$ in a manifold of dimension $n$. Define a new coordinate system $x^1, \ldots x^n$ by
$$
y^i=\sum_{j=1}^n a^i_j x^j ~~~~~~i= 1, \ldots n
$$

Then by the chain rule,
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j} = \sum_i \frac{\partial {y^i}}{\partial x^j} \frac{\partial }{\partial y^i} \tag{1}
$$

I see in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2573232/968391) the author called this use of the chain rule the "basis transformation rule".

Can someone provide an intuitive explanation for why (1) is true?

Comment: It *is* the chain rule. If the transformation is given by $y=\phi(x)$, differentiate a function $f(y) = f(\phi(x))=(f\circ\phi)(x)$.

Comment: The intuition comes from transforming coordinates of the differentials on open sets. In two dimensions think about how you would express $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ in terms of $f$'s polar coordinate representation $f(r, \theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every tangent vector $v \in T_x M$ can be written as $$v = a^i \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} \right\vert_{x} $$

where $a_i = v(y^i)$, since $$v(y^j) = a^i\left.\frac{\partial y^j}{\partial y^i} \right\vert_{x} = a^i \delta_{i}^j = a_j $$ So, taking $v = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$, we see that:

$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \right\vert_{x} = \left(\left.\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j} \right\vert_{x} \right)(y^i) \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} \right\vert_{x} = \left.\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j} \right\vert_{x}   \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} \right\vert_{x}  $$

Comment: This is a completely clear explanation on how to reach the result in (1). But I don't think you applied the chain rule here -- is there some alternative approach using the chain rule?

Comment: @IsaacR24 an alternative approach would be using the chain rule to prove that:

$$\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} \right\vert_{x} = \left.\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j} \right\vert_{x}   \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^i} \right\vert_{x} $$

for an arbitrary $f$. This could be done by using the definition of the partial derivatives in the manifold setting, writing $f \circ \varphi^{-1} = f \circ \psi^{-1} \circ \psi \circ \varphi^{-1}$ and using the chain rule on the latter expression. But that would just be needlessly complicated